# JavaScript Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'done' (ToDo Single File Component)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, templates, vuejs2, typeerror

I wanted to adapt a ToDo single file component which used localStorage to save elements.

[Here's](https://codepen.io/nourabusoud/pen/WMGZaL) a codepen of the version which uses localStorage.

[Here's](https://pastebin.com/h0iFvUbU) my adapted version. (Can't do a jsfiddle because it uses SharePoint)

I adapted the code and it almost works, except of one bug which one gets when ticking the box:

[image]

I don't know what exactly is the cause of the problem, but I assume it's this:

```
<li v-for="(item, index) in completed" v-bind:key="item.title">
    <input class="todo-checkbox" v-bind:id="'item_' + item.id" v-model="item.done" type="checkbox">
```

When I remove the `v-model="item.done"` from both `<input>`, then the bug doesn't appear anymore, but nothing happens when I check the box. (And I can only check the first element of the list)

I've been trying for hours, but can't figure it out (since I'm a beginner in vue) what solves the bug.

Does someone know how one can fix this issue?

Comment: Have you tried replacing `v-for="(item, index) in completed"` with `v-for="(item, index) in todoList"` to see if the error is coming or not? just for debugging purpose.

Comment: @palaѕн Yes, but the bug would still appear

Comment: Can you try to remove `v-model="item.done" ` from `class="todo-checkbox"` and see if the issue is still coming?

Comment: Have you verifed my suggestion to the previous version of the question? The `title` in `deleteItem` method?

Comment: Not sure what issue is happening in your end, as the codepen demo is working fine.

Comment: @palaѕн I just removed the `v-model="item.done" ` from both `<input>` and the bug doesn't appear anymore, but nothing happens when I check the box

Comment: Ok, that is the main issue. It means that `item` does not have a `done` property. You will have to debug the code to see why was `done` not set on `completed` array.

Comment: @palaѕн Thank you for the info. How can I set `done` on the `completed` array?

Comment: You don't need to, as it is a computed property deriving from `todoList` array. Which means that `todoList` array items itself don't have any `done` property. You can use `debugger` keyword and debug code where are you setting `todoList` and does it have the  `done` property first.

Comment: @palaѕн Alright, thanks for your help, I appreciate it